# Javascript arrays (corresponding)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html, css

I have problems with understanding what I have to write inside this code

(sorry it´s in German, it´s a corresponding array for images for JavaScript.)

```
function namenZuBildern(){ 
   var bilder = new Array( "000227", "000228",
   "000229", "000231", "000233", "000235", "000237", "000238", "000239", 
   "000241", "000242", "000245", "000247", "000248", "000249", "000250",
   "000252", "000253", "000254", "000258", "000259", "000261", "000262" ) ; 

   var index = document.getElementById('einform').person.selectedIndex;
   document.images[0].src="#" + bilder[index] + ".jpg"; 
}
```

**like what are all these numbers inside newAray()**. The positions of the pictures?

And I know I have to write the id inside

```
document.getElementById('...').person.selectedIndex;
```

but what about
    document.images[0].src="#" + bilder[index] + ".jpg"; 
**why is it [0] when I have 4 pictures?**

please help

Comment: it looks like the file name.

Comment: "*why is it [0] when i have 4 pictures*" Well someone is only setting the source of the first image....

Comment: "why is it [0] when i have 4 pictures" because it's a slideshow - it shows one picture after the other using the same element.

Comment: what do you mean with "when I have 4 pictures?"?

Answer (score 0):

Since the `bilder` array is being used to set the `src` value for the images, I would wager the values correspond to the filenames